# What's wrong with this merge sort java code with user input?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

```
    int n,l;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of elements in the array:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter "+n+" elements ");
    for( l=0; l< n; l++) {
        a[l] = s.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println( "Enter expected position after sorting:  ");
    p = s.nextInt();
    int a[l]=new int[n];
    Sort(a,0,n-1);
    printarray(p);int n,l;
```

https://pastebin.com/sSaCDE6v

> Blockquote

The last part of the code where I have problem, I put comment on that part to which is supposed to function. The problems 1,the comparison of two list, as the index of the 1st set of list should be store first and will use to the 2nd set of array list. 2nd is in the comment in the code.   [1](https://pastebin.com/sSaCDE6v)

Answer (score 0):

The Errors you did in the code:

```
Finished in N/A
Line 87: error: ']' expected [in MSort.java]
        int a[l]=new int[n];
              ^
Line 87: error: ';' expected [in MSort.java]
        int a[l]=new int[n];
               ^
Line 87: error: not a statement [in MSort.java]
        int a[l]=new int[n];
                 ^
Line 95: error: illegal start of expression [in MSort.java]
         if (p=l)){ System.out.println("Sorta Right");
                 ^
Line 96: error: 'else' without 'if' [in MSort.java]
     } else{
       ^
5 errors
```

Those all are syntactical errors.

After that in merge function after the main for loop you write while loops in this way -

```
while(i <= m )    
                 b[c++] = a[i++];
 
               while(j<=h)   
                 b[c++] = a[j++];
```

here the problem is proper indention, If you cant use proper indention then make sure you use curly braces on your code.